# Laravel middleware is not called in feature test

Tags: testing, laravel-7

I have a new middleware that works as expected in the browser. However, when I try to trigger the middleware via a feature test, the `handle()` is never called.

I understand I can write a unit test for this middleware, and should. But should my actual feature test be moved to a browser test?

```php
# Kernel.php

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            MyMiddleware::class,
            ...
```

```php
# MyMiddleware.php

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd('I can see this in the browser, but not in the Feature test. Doing some 302 magic here.');
```

```php
# Feature Test
    /**
     * @test
     * @return void
     */
    public function my_new_test(): void
    {
        $this->get('/test')
            ->assertStatus(302)
            ->assertRedirect($vanityDomain->getFallbackRedirectUrl('/non-matching-path'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me, not sure why yours is not working.
`middleware`

```php
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ('test' === $request->path()) {
            return redirect('/test1');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`feature test`

```php
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->get('/test')->assertStatus(302)->assertRedirect('test1');
    }
}
```

Btw, unit and feature tests just a way of grouping your tests. Does not matter where you put, they all behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

On laravel 8 I had to run `php artisan optimize` to get it working. Seems the route cache somehow needed to be cleared.